# Siimple Python. Not sure why my program is outputting this

Tags: python-3.x, output

I am making a program to take in a sentence, convert each word to pig latin, and then spit it back out as a sentence. I have no idea where I have messed up. I input a sentence and run it and it says

built-in method lower of str object at 0x03547D40

```
s = input("Input an English sentence: ")
s = s[:-1]
string = s.lower

vStr = ("a","e","i","o","u")



def findFirstVowel(word):
    for index in range(len(word)):
        if word[index] in vStr:
            return index
    return -1

def translateWord():       
        if(vowel == -1) or (vowel == 0):
           end = (word + "ay")

        else:
            end = (word[vowel:] + word[:vowel]+ "ay")


def pigLatinTranslator(string):
    for word in string:
        vowel = findFirstVowel(word)
        translateWord(vowel)

    return


print (string)
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! For future reference, it is typically smiled upon to include the full traceback, mainly as it includes the line number of the error. Plus, you may even find your error without needing to post!

Answer (score 2):

You have used the lower method incorrectly.
You should use it like this `string = s.lower()`.

The parentheses change everything. When you don't use it, Python returns an object.

Built-in function should always use `()`

Answer (score 0):

Here is the corrected version of the code which should work:

```
s = input("Input an English sentence: \n").strip()
string = s.lower() #lowercasing

vStr = ("a","e","i","o","u")

def findFirstVowel(word):
    for idx,chr in enumerate(word):
        if chr in vStr:
            return idx
    return -1

def translateWord(vowel, word):       
        if(vowel == -1) or (vowel == 0):
           end = (word + "ay")

        else:
            end = (word[vowel:] + word[:vowel]+ "ay")

def pigLatinTranslator(string):
    for word in string:
        vowel = findFirstVowel(word)
        translateWord(vowel,word)

    return

print(string)
```